# How to load content with next button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, angularjs

I have a form which requires 3 steps, 1 is a few details then when the user presses the "Next" button it moves on to the next step without using ajax and without checking if everything is correct.

I moved to angularJS today and would really like to get this to work.

Here is what i have.

```
<form id="mccheckout" method="post" action="{$smarty.server.PHP_SELF}?a=confproduct&amp;i={$i}">
    <input type="text" name="namefiled" id="namefiled" value="" required="" ng-maxlength="30" placeholder="Enter the name" ng-model="name" class="ng-valid ng-dirty">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

When i press next i want to load the next step of the form if the name field is correct.

The next step should be:

```
<input type="text" name="namefiled" id="namefiled" value="" required="" ng-maxlength="30" placeholder="Enter the password" ng-model="password" class="ng-valid ng-dirty">
```

This should be in the same `<form>` I dont want it to be outside the form, the submit button should only check if  everything is correct and then call for the next piece of the form.

Im not sure how to go about doing this and im fairly new to ajax. Should i load the form contents from the same page or an external file via ajax request?

Could you guys provide some example code on how you would do this.

Thank you for your time,

Comment: Why are you making the weird restrictions?

Comment: @stark what do you mena by restrictions? The form is actually much longer, those inputs are there as an example.

Comment: @user3446806, How many "steps" are there in your form?

Comment: Try this: http://casewarecomputers.com:8088/soHelp.html,  I create an array of ids what are elements in your form which I'm calling "Steps", along with a function to validate each step.  The main function validateForm() looks up the validation function for the current step, runs it, and if the result is True, advances to the next step and shows the field.  how that helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one potential way of doing it:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>IrishGeek82 SO Help File</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,300,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() 
                      {
                      }
                    );
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    .invalid
    {
        border:1px solid red;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function validateStep1()
    {
        return true;
    }

    function validateStep2()
    {
        return true;
    }

    function validateStep3()
    {
        return true;
    }

    function validateStep4()
    {
        return false;
    }

    //Start at step 0
    var currStep = 0;

    //Each "step" refers to an element in your form that has an ID.
    //We include a reference to a validation function in the JSON String
    //So we can validate the field.
    var steps    = [{"stepName":"step1","validationMethod":validateStep1},
                    {"stepName":"step2","validationMethod":validateStep2},
                    {"stepName":"step3","validationMethod":validateStep3},
                    {"stepName":"step4","validationMethod":validateStep4}];

    //This function runs the validation routine on the current 
    //step and advances to the next step on TRUE.
    function validateForm(formObj)
    {
        console.log("Curr Step:"+currStep);

        //You can perform your validation in here and only advance to the next step if you can.
        //You could just as easily use anonymous functions in the JSON Object above.
        if (steps[currStep].validationMethod())
        {
            currStep++;

            if (currStep <= steps.length)
            {
                $("#"+steps[currStep].stepName).css("display","block");
                console.log("Curr Step:"+currStep);
            }
            else
            {
                currStep--;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $("#"+steps[currStep].stepName).addClass("invalid");
        }
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="someForm" name="someForm" action="#" method="get">

    <input type="text" id="step1" name="step1" style="display:block;" value=""/>
    <input type="text" id="step2" name="step2" style="display:none;" value=""/>
    <input type="text" id="step3" name="step3" style="display:none;" value=""/>    
    <input type="text" id="step4" name="step4" style="display:none;" value=""/>
    <hr>
    <button id="navButton" onclick="validateForm('someForm');return false;">Next</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I created an array of ids that are elements in your form along with a function to validate each step.

The main function validateForm() looks up the validation function for the current step, runs it, and if the result is True, advances to the next step and shows the field.

Please let me know if that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

action of submit: server side script.

content of form changeable with style.visibility or style.display

content of sUBMIT button changeable witout reload of document ?
it means:  
 document.getElementById("mccheckout").action    this porperty changeable without reload of document ?

make more than 1 FORM (1 FORM per step)
if step1-form okay make step2-form visible und step1-form hidden (step3-form is hidden).

....